# Control the "TV remote"

Tags: arduino-uno, remote-control

My idea is to use Arduino to control the TV remote. Not make the Arduino become a TV remote, I want to make an Arduino that can touch button of a remote control.

Any ideas?

Comment: A few more details? Physically touch the buttons? Electrically close them? Which remote?

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://arduino.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) - people are likely to vote to close this as too broad. Asking if anyone has "any ideas" is a rather broad question. Try to narrow it down to something more answerable.

Comment: Sending the signals directly will be a far better idea.

Comment: I agree with Chris, if you've got a (unconventional) design choice or limitation, you may want to expand on it and explain why. There may be other options which fit your limitations. In order to solve a problem, we'll first need to know what problem (and why).

Answer (score 2):

My rather fancy solution would be to make a 3 axis device with x and y controlled by stepper motors and z a simple solenoid to press the buttons.
For extra marks you could add a camera and try to recognise the buttons in software so any remote would work.
How do you plan to control the arduino?  Perhaps with a remote controller?

Comment: Nice answer. Using a remote to control the Arduino that controls the remote certainly is an interesting idea.